# simplejson ImportError when I try to create a new conda environment or install a package

Tags: python, python-requests, conda

I'm trying to use Conda as I usually do in order to create a new environment and install a new package, but I receive this error message:

```
/cluster/home/2530631/mambaforge/lib/python3.10/site-packages/_distutils_hack/__init__.py:33: UserWarning: Setuptools is replacing distutils.
  warnings.warn("Setuptools is replacing distutils.")

# >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ERROR REPORT <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/cluster/home/2530631/mambaforge/lib/python3.10/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 1118, in __call__
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/cluster/home/2530631/mambaforge/lib/python3.10/site-packages/conda/cli/main.py", line 69, in main_subshell
        exit_code = do_call(args, p)
      File "/cluster/home/2530631/mambaforge/lib/python3.10/site-packages/conda/cli/conda_argparse.py", line 89, in do_call
        module = import_module(relative_mod, __name__.rsplit('.', 1)[0])
      File "/cluster/home/2530631/mambaforge/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
        return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
      File "/cluster/home/2530631/mambaforge/lib/python3.10/site-packages/conda/cli/main_create.py", line 14, in <module>
        from ..notices import notices
      File "/cluster/home/2530631/mambaforge/lib/python3.10/site-packages/conda/notices/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
        from .core import notices  # noqa: F401
      File "/cluster/home/2530631/mambaforge/lib/python3.10/site-packages/conda/notices/core.py", line 15, in <module>
        from . import fetch
      File "/cluster/home/2530631/mambaforge/lib/python3.10/site-packages/conda/notices/fetch.py", line 8, in <module>
        import requests
      File "/cluster/home/2530631/mambaforge/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/__init__.py", line 45, in <module>
        from .exceptions import RequestsDependencyWarning
      File "/cluster/home/2530631/mambaforge/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/exceptions.py", line 9, in <module>
        from .compat import JSONDecodeError as CompatJSONDecodeError
      File "/cluster/home/2530631/mambaforge/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/compat.py", line 40, in <module>
        from simplejson import JSONDecodeError
    ImportError: cannot import name 'JSONDecodeError' from 'simplejson' (unknown location)
```

For your knowledge, I'm here reporting some conda/mamba packages' versions as suggested:

```
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
conda                     22.11.1         py310hff52083_1    conda-forge
conda-package-handling    2.0.2              pyh38be061_0    conda-forge
conda-package-streaming   0.7.0              pyhd8ed1ab_1    conda-forge
fonts-conda-ecosystem     1                             0    conda-forge
fonts-conda-forge         1                             0    conda-forge
libmamba                  1.0.0                h9eff5f0_2    conda-forge
libmambapy                1.0.0           py310hd5a56e8_2    conda-forge
mamba                     1.0.0           py310h51d5547_2    conda-forge
python                    3.10.6          ha86cf86_0_cpython    conda-forge
python_abi                3.10                    3_cp310    conda-forge
requests                  2.28.2             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
setuptools                66.1.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
```

I've simply tried to run this command using the HPC cluster:

```bash
conda create -n krak_brack
```

And I expected the usual Conda messages to proceed to the new environment creation. As long as I can remember, I did not modify anything in the last days.

Comment: @Riksal96 Do you know why simplejson is installed? It is _not_ actually a dependency of requests, and is only there for historical reasons (remnant of support for very old Python versions where stdlib json was inferior). Can you enter the REPL and tell  us what `import simplejson; print(simplejson.__file__)` says?

Comment: Actually `simplejson.__file__` will probably be `None`, so tell us what `simplejson.__path__` has.

Answer (score 1):

The error message has a hint at the end:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'JSONDecodeError' from 'simplejson' (unknown location)
```

That ***(unknown location)*** part is what you get when you have an empty directory lying around, perhaps from some botched uninstall. The directory name can be successfully imported as an [implicit namespace package](https://peps.python.org/pep-0420/):

```
$ mkdir simplejson
$ python3
>>> import simplejson
>>> simplejson
<module 'simplejson' (<_frozen_importlib_external._NamespaceLoader object at 0xdeadbeef>)>
```

However, it will appear to be empty and have "unknown location" according to importlib loaders:

```
>>> from simplejson import JSONDecodeError
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'JSONDecodeError' from 'simplejson' (unknown location)
```

This apparently confuses requests 2.28.2 which has [a crude way](https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/v2.28.2/requests/compat.py#L32-L35) of seeing if simplejson is installed.

The solution is to look through your `sys.path` and find which entry contains a subdirectory called `simplejson` *without* an `__init__.py` in it, and remove that (possibly empty) directory.